# Sony Action Camera API

Tags: camera, sony

We need to develop an appliacation using the Sony Action Cam and the Camera Remote Api.

Our application needs to give the see the files recorded and to transfer the recorded video files from the camera to the smart Phone or to a PC using the Wi-Fi.

As far as we see there is not such a command documented, but it should be possible because you have an application that is able to transfer the files to a smart Phone.

Is it possible to have a more complete documentation?

Thank you

Giuliano C.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is complete, unfortunately the API functionality you are asking about is private and only available to the PlayMemories app at this time.  Will keep you updated if there are any changes to that.

Comment: What is the reason for excluding fundamental functionality from the Camera API? Is Sony really interested in powerful 3rd party applications?

Answer (score 1):

That is not entirely true.  Sony has shared that capability with other third party apps, (V1 -Interactive Frontiers) but chooses not to make it available to everyone.  Until they do the API really has no commercial value.  I have asked several times why they chose not to publish that part of the API, but never gotten an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to unlock this Part of the API. Then you can switch from "Remote Shooting" to "Transfer Mode". But this enables only the UPNP of the Camera so you can get (readonly) the files throught the windows explorer.